Modules are being reloaded on every import (not using cache)
When I try to import from a module in my NextJS custom server app such as import { registerStartOfGuildTriviaListener } from '@/lib/trivia-manager'; in more than one place, the module gets reloaded rather than using what has already been loaded. This is a problem for me because I am keeping some data in this module that I would like to use all over my app, but when I go to try and get that data elsewhere, it has been re-initialized and no longer exists.
I have been looking for a solution for the last couple days and I just cannot find one. I have tried using an absolute path rather than the path alias (@) and it still doesn't work FYI.
Here is my complete tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

I am using the tsx compiler like so: npx tsx server.ts

This problem is likely happening because tsx uses a watch mode. Try to ignore the file that is giving you problems:
tsx watch --ignore ./file.ts


I just tried to use tsx watch --ignore ./* server.ts and it did not seem to fix the issue :(
